# Calculating the difference between each row and min/max row in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, min

I have a table that look like this:

```
EmpID Salary
1     20
2     5
3     10
4     12
5     4
6     6
```

And I want to caluculate for each EmpID the difference between assigned salary and minimum salary and between this salary and maximum salary. Like this:

```
Min(Salary) = 4
Max(Salary) = 20
```

So my output should look like this:

```
 EmpID Salary Diff1 Diff2
    1     20   16     0
    2     5    1     -15
    3     10   6     -10
    4     12   8     -8
    5     4    0     -16
    6     6    2     -12
```

I try do this in two ways, but have no idea what to do next.

**My script:**

```
SELECT EmpID, Salary,
    Salary - MIN(Salary) AS Diff1,
    Salary - MAX(Salary) AS Diff2
from MyTable
group by EmpID, Salary
```

Second approach:

```
  SELECT EmpID, Salary,
        Salary - MIN(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY salary) AS Diff1,
        Salary - MAX(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY salary) AS Diff2
    from MyTable
    group by EmpID, Salary
```

But it doesnt work. I do something wrong.

Comment: What purpose does `GROUP BY` serve in your queries?

Comment: Without it I get error that I can't use EmpID and Salary in Select statement.

Comment: You need to understand syntax you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `group by` from your query also `Partition by` and `order by` in `Over` Clause

```
SELECT EmpID, Salary,
    Salary - MIN(Salary) OVER() AS Diff1,
    Salary - MAX(Salary) OVER() AS Diff2
from MyTable
```

or another way is doing by using `Sub-Query` which less efficient

```
SELECT EmpID, Salary,
    Salary - (select MIN(Salary) from MyTable) AS Diff1,
    Salary - (select MAX(Salary) from MyTable) AS Diff2
from MyTable
```